# dojo mouseover with delay

Tags: javascript, dojo

I wish to do something like as follows:

- When the mouse goes over to some element, record it
- If the mouse stays there for 3 seconds, then execute some action `f()` for that element
- If the mouse leaves that element before 3 seconds, then the action should not be executed.

How can I implement this delayed execution with possible cancellation? An answer using DOJO library would be nicer since I am using DOJO toolkit in my project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var delay = 3000;

dojo.forEach(dojo.query(".some-element-set"), function(element) {
    dojo.connect(element, "onmouseover", function() {
        // dojo.partial(f, this.id) will apply `this.id` to `f`, but it 
        // will not execute it and will only a new function
        this._timer = setTimeout(dojo.partial(f, this.id), delay);
    });

    dojo.connect(element, "onmouseout", function() {
        // this._timer was set as an element attribute in the above event 
        // handler so we don't have to keep track of them separately in 
        // some silly array/object
        clearTimeout(this._timer);
    });
});
```

See the [query](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/query), [forEach](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/forEach), [connect](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/connect) and [partial](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/partial) documentation for more information.

Edit: I've update my answer per the OP's comment

Comment: This looks great. I guess I need a more generalized version of this. I have a set of elements (each with distinct id), and I need to invoke the function f with the id of the element. Would that be too difficult?